# calculate the distance of point of canvas in android

Tags: java, android, canvas, coordinates, point

I want to do android apps to calculate distance point of canvas on android. Basically I have 4 points, `(x1,y1)(x2,y2),(x3,y3) and (x4,y4).`  What I want to do is to calculate ratio length of maximum,D1 over length of minimum,D2..for D1, I need to calculate the distance between two points`(x1,y1)(x2,y2)` and for D2, I need to calculate distance for another points `(x3,y3)(x4,y4)`.. for the points, it just user entry. the user will put the value and straightly calculate the ratio D1/D2.

Can someone help me? I know the formula but not sure how to do the function.

```
public class MainActivity5 extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

EditText editText1;
EditText editText2;
EditText editText3;
EditText editText4;
EditText editText5;
EditText editText6;
EditText editText7;
EditText editText8;
Button button1;
TextView tvResult;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity5);


      // find the elements
    EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    EditText editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    EditText editText3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    EditText editText4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    EditText editText5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    EditText editText6 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
    EditText editText7 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText6);
    EditText editText8 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText7);


    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    tvResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvResult);

    // set a listener
    button1.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
  }

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 String x1 = editText1.getText().toString();
 String y1 = editText2.getText().toString();
 String x2 = editText3.getText().toString();
 String y2 = editText4.getText().toString();
 String x3 = editText5.getText().toString();
 String y3 = editText6.getText().toString();
 String x4 = editText7.getText().toString();
 String y4 = editText8.getText().toString();

 //calculating distance
 double dist = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x1 - x2, 2) + Math.pow(y1- y2, 2));

 //what should i put here
 }
```

Comment: What are those edit texts suppose to be? Integers?

Comment: edit texts are integers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse the strings before you can pass them into a `Math` method. A `try-catch` block can be used to check for invalid number cases.

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    try {
        double x1 = Double.parseDouble(editText1.getText().toString());
        double y1 = Double.parseDouble(editText2.getText().toString());
        double x2 = Double.parseDouble(editText3.getText().toString());
        double y2 = Double.parseDouble(editText4.getText().toString());
        double x3 = Double.parseDouble(editText5.getText().toString());
        double y3 = Double.parseDouble(editText6.getText().toString());
        double x4 = Double.parseDouble(editText7.getText().toString());
        double y4 = Double.parseDouble(editText8.getText().toString());

        //calculating distance
        double d1 = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x1 - x2, 2) + Math.pow(y1- y2, 2));
        double d2 = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x3 - x4, 2) + Math.pow(y3- y4, 2));

        tvResult.setText(Double.toString(d1/d2));
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {

    }
}
```

Comment: thanks ! what happen to catch there? i don't get it. can u explain?

Comment: I guess you got a `NumberFormatException`? Log something in the catch.

Comment: What error? And do you think someone will be able to help you with "still got error"?

Comment: lol. sorry. when i click the button to get the result, apps suddenly stop. by the way, do i need to declare d1 and d2?  later i post the logcat

Comment: Oh, I see your edit texts are all null because you created a local variable in your `onCreate` for them. Just set `editText1 =` rather than decalring another `EditText`: `EditText editText1 =`